# Limit of $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}$ using weaker form of Stirling approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to reprove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}=0$ using weaker form of Stirling approximation. More precisely, I want to use that $n! \sim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{n}{e})^n$. If I am not mistaken, I have $(2n)!\sim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}$ and $(n!)^2 \sim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}$. Hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{2^{2n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}}=1,$ which is wrong.

What is the mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: Use $\left(\frac 2 e\right)^n\, \sqrt n$. This makes everything different.

Comment: The reason is in the weak form. Use the full one.

Comment: The claim $n!\sim n^ne^{-n}$ is wrong. The ratio $n!/(n^ne^{-n})$  tends to infinity. I wouldn'f involve Stirling into a false statement.